# Optimistic lock mode and session.get() vs session.createQuery()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple entity with one attribute, and version for optimistic lock mode.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private Long version;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

}
```

I want to work with instance in detached state.

Step 1. I open a session somehow load a instance, close the session.

```
Session session = ... ;
Person person = session.get(Person.class, 1);
session.close();
```

Step 2. I change the attribute value of person in detached state.

```
person.setName("Bob");
```

Step 3. I open new session, merge the instance and ask session to return instance for me with .get method

```
Session session = ... ;
person = session.merge(person);
// something happen there
// and then we decide to get our instance from session
person = session.get(Person.class, 1); 

System.out.println(person.getVersion()); // result is 0
```

Step 4. I do the same things as in step 3 but with query.

```
Session session = ... ;
person = session.merge(person);
// something happen there
// and then we decide to get our instance from session
Query<Person> query = session.createQuery("from Person p where p.id = :id", Person.class);
query.setParameter("id", 1L);
person = query.list().iterator().next();

System.out.println(person.getVersion()); // result is 1
```

So, what the difference here? Both cases hit the database, but only second case do the version update (and this behavior seems wrong for me, because if I repeat step 4 two times I will get the DbConcurrentModificationException exception). Where I miss something? Where I can read about this? Why the version updated not in flush time?

Hibernate 5.4.12.Final

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not take into account [flushing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing).

> Flushing is the process of synchronizing the state of the persistence context with the underlying database.
>
> 6.1. AUTO flush
>
> By default, Hibernate uses the AUTO flush mode which triggers a flush in the following circumstances:
>
> - prior to committing a Transaction
> - prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued entity actions
> - before executing any native SQL query that has no registered synchronization

So, when you execute your query

```java
Query<Person> query = session.createQuery("from Person p where p.id = :id", Person.class);
```

Hibernate implicit synchronizes the state of the persistence context with the database.

But when you call the `merge` method you should do it by yourself.

```java
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Person person = session.get(Person.class, 1L);
session.close();

person.setName("Bob");

Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction2 = session2.beginTransaction();

person = (Person) session2.merge(person);
session2.flush();

System.out.println(person.getVersion()); // here version will be updated

transaction2.commit();
session2.close();
```